# How to create and restore backup of database using winform?

Tags: c#

I'm making an application and I want to give a button to create Backup of database on the users desired location; like we save any file on any destination on computer and one button to restore the backup of whole database. How to accomplish this task?

I'm making backup through this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"backup database StockDB to disk ='d:\StockDBBackUp1.bak' with init,stats=10", ConnectionClass.OpenConnection());  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now if I give a folder name `d:\Backup\StockDBBackUp1.bak` then it should check that is the folder is there already. If not, then it should to create the folder and create the backup.

Comment: sir how can i create a winform data of sql server backup? can i make backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.IO` functions to accomplish creating the directory:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\Backup"))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Backup");
```

Comment: how to restore the backup to again in main database?

Comment: Take a look at the [RESTORE command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx). However, I would recommend using SMO to backup/restore your database. [See this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_Server_2005_Database.aspx) for an example.

Comment: sir can i make backup of data of sql server. i am using c# and winform i want user to backup his database so can i make backup?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
            DateTime PD = new DateTime(DateTime.Today);
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = PD.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = " files|*.bak;*.BAK";
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "d:";
            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    string path = string.Empty;
                    path = saveFileDialog1.FileName;

                    path = path.Replace("\\", "//");
                    bool bBackUpStatus = true;
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        if (MessageBox.Show(@"do you want a new one?", "the file is existing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                        }
                        else
                            bBackUpStatus = false;
                    }
                    if (bBackUpStatus)
                    {
                        //Connect to DB
                        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local); Data Source=LocalHost; DataBase=Exchange; UID=sa; Pwd=sql");
                        //string con = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirector  y|\SRVCARD.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
                        if (Conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
                        {
                            Conn.Close();
                        }
                        Conn.Open();
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"backup database Exchange To Disk='" + path + "' with stats=10", Conn);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Conn.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("Backup successfully", "Backup", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("please change the path");
                    //MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please, make proper code formatting. Also, pure-code answers without explanation are of low quality.