# backup and restore the database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce, backup, database-backups

I am a newbie studying `c#` from last 3 months and I am using sql server as my database. I go to menu and create a service based database, and makes table there I am working on winform I have menu datagridview which shows the data in specified form. Now I want to know: can I make a database copy in particular folder or file? is it possible? I've heard that I can load csv file into datagriview. How can I make csv file, or something diffrent file like `.mdf` so that I can restore after accidentally deletes the data. Is there any other method?

I have got some hint from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114046/how-to-create-and-restore-backup-of-database-using-winform) but it is incomplete.

Comment: If your concern is about deleting data accidently, you should read about transactions. Right?

Comment: Why would you "accidentally" delete data..also why would you want to store your data backup in a .csv file.. why not use the DBMS to create a backup or implement some sort of replication process where you can have an exact copy of the existing data..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE yess sir you can suggest that method of replication of data i want that only. i am bad in english so i cant express what can i do?

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi i want to make backup so that when i pc is formated then i can restore the data. that way. now you understood

Comment: the SQL Server Database if setup properly has a .BAK file if you so choose to create a backup.. I would suggest reading articles on SQL Server and how to create and Restore Backups

Comment: sir where i can find such article? to make .bak file

Answer (score 1):

Why do not use the backup tools included in sql server (ms sql management studio)?
You can program periodic backups on the server (independently of the execution or not of your  client program.

Yes, you can export to csv or other text format, but it is not the recommended way. What if you are in the middle of a transaction: do you should copy that data? or discard it?
If you program the backup from your client, you must think about the eventual restore process. Do you want write a restore program also? You should have in mind the restore order of the tables. What if you change the structure of your database in a future?

Conclusion: use standard processes to backup/restore your database unless you have a strong reason not to.

Comment: sir so what can i do here which process i can use? i am totally blank what to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL server management studio to make and restore back up. Pls download SQL server management studio, just google it's very easy to find. Then create or attach your database. Right click on the database there is a database context menu then select all tasks. You should be able to see back up restore and other options. Pls follow some YouTube videos on this topic that should get you started.

Comment: qamar bhai. i am providing my software user to create a backup and restore funtionality. so i dont want to install sql management in my client computer. so whats the other way to create a backup?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below link. It's all about maintaining a database in SQL Compact Edition. Check out the "Backup/Restore/Drop" section at the end:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172411(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: sir i use .mdf file for my app i.e service based data. so can i shift my whole opetation to local data which is .sdf file? is there any diffrence?

Comment: Of course there are plenty of differences between using .mdf and .sdf. ".sdf" extension shows that your database is Compact Edition which is specialized for windows mobile and some small databases. ".mdf" (with another ".ldf" file in the same location) shows that you are using one of the database engines provided by Microsoft. SQL Express and SQL Server are two editions that use these extensions for the databases. About the differences, I think you should have a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/aac9e792-3cbf-424b-9e1c-6f84b2acf044